"I was forced to use a food bank." VS "I had to use a food bank."
"I was forced to use a food bank after my cancer diagnosis."
"I had to use a food bank after my cancer diagnosis."
To me, as a non-native speaker, both sentences almost mean the same, however the expression "I was forced to do something ...." sounds like "Someone or something physically forced me to do it", whereas in this context in doesn't seem to be the case.
But then "I was forced to do ...." seems to mean the same as "I had to do ...", because "have to" also implies external factors cause you to do do something. So aren't they almost the same in meaning?

In this case, the person's financial situation forced them to use the food bank. Force doesn't have to be physical.

They have different meanings.

I was forced to use a food bank ...


I had to use a food bank ...

Had to usually doesn't have the connotation of a person being forced to do something.
The person may have to do that something out of necessity, but it is milder than being forced to do it.

When someone says "I was forced to {do something}" the meaning can be paraphrased as  "under the circumstances I had no other choice"  when there is no mention of any person that is making them do the thing under duress by using intimidation of some kind, such as the threat of physical harm to themselves or the people they care about.
The phrase is used often of circumstances that are rather trivial in the grand scheme of things:

The regional rail workers were on strike so I was forced to take the bus.


I upvoted this but I wish you'd take out the AmE thing.

@Lambie  If you know it to be true of BrE as well, just add a comment to that effect. I do not know if the Brits use it as loosely as it is used in AmE.

It's in the Oxford online under BrE: I was forced to take a taxi because the last bus had left.

"Was forced to" is in passive voice, which is why it carries the connotation that the "I" in these sentences is the target (or "grammatical patient") of an action by an (unspecified) agent or actor. In English, the verbs "be", or sometimes "get", are used as auxiliary ("was" is "be" in the past tense) to mark clauses in passive voice.
For the verbs "have", or, analogously, "must" or "need", the person that takes the role of needing is the subject of the verb instead, which is why there is no other actor implied by the sentence.
However, for the first sentence, you can still have an actor that is not necessarily a person, for example, you can be "forced [by circumstances] to use a food bank". Specifically with the second part of the sentence mentioning the cancer diagnosis, it can be easy to make the assumption that the cancer is what acted to cause the "force" in "forced to".
I don't know what sentences you find more difficult to use "forced to", but it's possible that the reason you find them more difficult is because there isn't such a convenient agent nearby in the same sentence.
